# I am writing a Batch file to uninstall ESET Nod 32 how to I program it to enter a password?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, powershell-2.0

I work for IT and I need to figure this out. I'm a bit new so please go easy! 
This is what I have so far:

```
Msiexec /uninstall {50E9E32F-063A-412A-9627-553D5DA57C17} /quiet
```

I need it to enter a password but there is no GUI prompt that is an issue. I can get the program to uninstall on my computer but not on others. I do have Administrator powers so if you have other suggestions please feel free I'm willing to use Power shell as well.

Comment: Does the program prompt a user for  a password? If so, is it UAC that's popping up?

Answer (score 0):

To do a silent removal with the option to reboot or not do this.

```
msiexec.exe /x {50E9E32F-063A-412A-9627-553D5DA57C17} /qb! /promptrestart
```